how to disable ssl verification for google-cloud-aiplatform
We are in a situation where we need to disable ssl verification when using google-cloud-aiplatform in python. Currently getting the following certificate error :

503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:{an ip address, hidden for security}:443: Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1654] Handshake failed with
fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL
routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

I have tried the following code as well with no luck:
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443')

aiplatform.init(
    project=common.model_config['project_id'],
    staging_bucket=common.model_config['bucket_uri'],
    location =common.model_config['region'],
     credentials=channel)


I had a quick look at the library's source code and was not able to determine how to do this. The init function sets Config class properties that are used subsequently but, it doesn't directly represent the gRPC channel and can't be used as you tried. There may be a documented way (I couldn't find) to do this either in code or through an environment variable but I was unable to find such a solution.

Depending on your urgency and complexity, you could make the gRPC calls directly. All Google's gRPC services are documented in the Google APIs repo including aiplatform. This lower-level access should permit you to grpc.insecure_channel against Google's public endpoints
